# Не работают анимации в Android приложении Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Пытаюсь сделать анимацию перехода между активностями.

```kotlin
fun openActivity2 (view:View) {
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left)
    val intent = Intent(this, Registration::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}

val register = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.register_link_textview)
register.setOnClickListener() {
    Log.e("test_REG_DEB", "registration_debug")
    openActivity2(register)
}
```

Comment: Вами необходимо более подробно описать свой вопрос, если вы хотите получить ответ. Что значит нет работает? Какая анимация ожидается? Где собственно код анимации?

Comment: Извиняюсь,распишу более подробно.При нажатии на TextView сменяется активность,но без анимации,которую я пытаюсь вызвать.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="600"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="100%" />
</set>

Comment: <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="600"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте данную команду:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left)
```

использовать уже после `startActivity()`:

```
Intent newsIntent = new Intent(ZPFActivity.this, More2013Activity.class);
startActivity(newsIntent);
finish();
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_no_move, R.anim.fade);
```

[Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20745079/overridependingtransition-not-working) аналогичная проблема.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное за ссылку!Проблема была в том,что изначально телефон запрещает проигрывать анимации с приложений,установленных с юсб. Всего вам наилучшего?!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.